# Style all elements that have a certain preceding tag with a specific child

Tags: html, css

So I have a kind of advanced CSS question:

Let's say I have following html structure:

```html
<div id="container">
  <label id="child"></label>
</div>
<a id="stylethis"></a>
```

Now, I know you can style the anchor when you check for the preceding div:
`#container ~ #stylethis`

Except, I don't want to style this if it has just a container in front of it, but rather when the container has a label with id child.
So what I would have done is:
`#container #child ~ #stylethis`

Well, problem is that this doesn't work.
So my question is how can achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance,

Billy Cottrell

Comment: you cannot, you are missing the parent selector to go from child to container and then use `~`

Comment: I just found out that it is possible with following css:
`#container:has(#child) ~ #stylethis` Although that the `:has` pseudo selector is still in exerimental mode